# Is “fat book” correct to speak?

Tags: grammar

In a video I heard someone talking about very **thick** books.

So I thought if ***thick** book* was correct to say 
or is ***fat** book* correct?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Oxford Thesaurus](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/fat), it seems correct. It even mentions "books" explicitly.

[**fat**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/fat)

> 3 *those **fat books** you're always reading*
>
> SYNONYMS **thick**, big, chunky, substantial, extended, long

Comment: I'd add that, while it's grammatically correct, it's a bit of an odd way to describe a book. Under normal circumstances I'd use *thick* or *big*. But I could definitely see it being used in a literary context.

Answer (score -3):

It depends on the circumstances. But I do have heard of something like 'Keep the content of the book lean':)

Comment: What circumstances does it depend on?

Comment: Words and phrases are invented by some people. If a term makes sense, then it's a correct one. isn't it? Those who are viewing or answering this question do know what 'fat book' is. That's the circumstance.

Comment: I think that you're receiving negative votes because you haven't described those circustances and you haven't referenced any sources to back up your statements.